# How to install an extension in gitpod?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, gitpod

When I try to drag and drop a .vsix file from my PC, it stats it as invalid.

Is there any other way or am I going wrong at any step ?

Comment: Could you share an image of the error? What you are saying sounds like the right way of doing it but it may be that the extension file is invalid. Maybe if you post the image we will have more information.

Answer (score 0):

Support for dropping `vsix` files on the extension view was just added in 1.47.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_47.md#install-vsix-through-dragndrop

> **Install VSIX through drag'n'drop**
>
> VS Code now supports installing an extension VSIX file through
> drag'n'drop onto the Extensions view.